# Grep looking for something that fits one paramter but NOT the other

Tags: grep

In my data set, we have a multitude of emails that must be parsed (alongside a myriad of other unrelated information like phone numbers and addresses and such.)

I am attempting to look for something that meets the criteria of an email, but does not have the proper format of an email. So, I tried using grep's "AND" function, wherein it fits the *second* parameter but not the first.

```
grep -E -c -v "^[a-mA-M][a-zA-Z]*\.@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"Data.bash | grep @ Data.bash
```

How should I be implementing this? As this just finds anything with an @ in it (as the first parameter returns 0 and the second is just finding everything with an @ in it).

In short, How do I AND two conditions together in grep?

**EDIT: Sample Data**

An email address has a user-id and domain names can consist of letters, numbers,
periods, and dashes.

```
Matches:
saltypickle@gmail.com
saltypickle@g-mail.com

No Match:
saltypickle@g^mail.com
saltypickle@.
@saltyPickle@
saltyPickle@
```

Comment: Some sample data showing matching and non matching inputs would be nice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -P '^\w+@[[:alnum:]-.]+.com' inputfile
saltypickle@gmail.com
saltypickle@g-mail.com
```

This will allow any alpha ,number, `-` or `.` as domain name.

Following will print invalid email addresses:

```
grep -vP '^\w+@[[:alnum:]-.]+.com' inputfile
saltypickle@g^mail.com
saltypickle@.
@saltyPickle@
saltyPickle@
```

Comment: This does what I had done, however, I need to be considering NOT a valid email address. I.E. grep -v -P '^\w+@[[:alnum:]-.]+.com' AND grep "@"

Comment: The logic needs  to fulfill that it does not meet the desired parameters (as you had stated) but that it *does* contain an @

Comment: you should use `grep -vP '^\w+@[[:alnum:]-.]+.com'|grep @` ,if I understood your requirement right. However, the regex `^\w+@[[:alnum:]-.]+.com` mandate presence of `@` in the string.